# Axapta: How to load an image from a file on disk into a grid with a Window Control

Tags: image, window, x++, axapta

I have been trying:

1. to load an image into a window control with a datamethod that loads the file into a bitmap, returning a bitmap. This makes Axapta Crash.
2. When doing the same but returning an image does not do anything.
3. using the "active" method on the data source has some success if I set the "imagename" to the filename and the autodecalaration property to "true" on the window component. The Grid does not refresh properly and the pictures dissappear and reappear (while you change rows) for a while until it seems satisfied and then  it stays on the screen.

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer - it would help if the documentation was better.

On the WindowControl: Simply link the datasource to the **table** containing the field with the string(text) of the full path and filename; and link the datafield to that **field**. Hey - it works like a charm. I have been trying to return images and bitmaps all the time from a datamethod.